# FileNotFoundError File does not exist

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("E:\YangJian\jupyter notebook\movie_metadata.csv")
train = pd.read_csv("E:\YangJian\jupyter notebook\train_modified.csv")
```

when i run "df",it's ok,but when i run "train",it's turns out as follows:
File b'E:\YangJian\jupyter notebook\train_modified.csv' does not exist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHqb6.jpg)

Comment: Does the file exist at that location?

Comment: Yes ,both the two files exist.

Answer (score 2):

The second path contains `\t` that becomes a tab character. It turns the path to `'E:\YangJian\jupyter notebook    rain_modified.csv'`

The solution is to always use raw strings when dealing with paths. Add `r` before the string literal:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"E:\YangJian\jupyter notebook\movie_metadata.csv")
#                ^
train = pd.read_csv(r"E:\YangJian\jupyter notebook\train_modified.csv")
#                   ^
```